# joomla sidebar to embed module ot article

Tags: joomla3.0

I want to add to a joomla website a sidebar like this site on the left side [joomla site with sidebars](http://www.perfect-web.co/joomla/popup-box-with-embedded-article-module-iframe)

How can I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- css property 'position:fixed' can be used to stick element to certain
  position.

to open stuff in popup try

```
JHTML::_('behavior.modal');

image
------
<a class="modal" href="/image/path/my-image.jpg" title="Preview Image">
  <img src="/images/icon-16-media.png" alt="Preview Image" />
</a>

page
----
<a class="modal" href="/component/mycomponent/?view=myview&layout=mylayout&tmpl=component" rel="{handler: 'iframe', size: {x: 600, y: 400}}" title="Display Definitions">
  This is a link to display content
</a>

load div
--------

<a class="modal" href="#mydiv">
</a>

<div style="display:none">
    <div id="mydiv">
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: hello and thank you I am new to joomla I need step by step guide to this, thank you again I am novice.

Comment: for css postion fixed: http://www.w3schools.com/css/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_position_fixed and for light box https://www.spiralscripts.co.uk/Joomla-Tips/using-modal-windows-with-joomla.html